# Delete all the stopped containers (on Windows)?

Tags: windows, docker

On Linux I can delete all of the stopped containers with this handy one-liner:

```
$ docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)
```

It's documented here: [Remove all stopped containers](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rm/#remove-all-stopped-containers)

But what's the equivalent syntax for Windows?

Comment: what happens if you run the same command in Windows? the doc doesn't say it is linux specific.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use `docker container prune` to remove all stopped containers (or `docker system prune` to cleanup other unused resources, such as unused networks, unused images, etc.

More information can be found in the [reference documentation for this command](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/)

Comment: So if I use both of those commands will that free up any and all redundant docker-related resources on my host?

Comment: If you want to cleanup everything, you'd only need `docker system prune` (but make yourself familiar with its options, as (for example) volumes are not removed by default because they may contain important data). `system prune` is a "wrapper" for `container prune`, `image prune`, `network prune`, etc. You can use the `<something> prune` commands if you only want to be more "specific" (for example, only cleanup "containers" but not "images")

Answer (score 0):

In **CMD** terminal you can run:

```
FOR /f "tokens=*" %i IN ('docker ps -aq') DO docker rm %i
```

In **Powershell** terminal you can run:

```
docker ps -aq | % { docker rm $_ }
```

In **Git Bash** terminal you can run:

```
docker rm $(docker ps -aq)
```